# WPML Redirect users based on wordpress profile settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I am developing a WooCommerce wholesaler shop in 5 languages using WPML.

Our languages are:

- Danish(main language)
- German
- English
- Swedish
- Norwegian

In our scenario, both Sweden + Norway have been translated into English. So we only have 3 languages on the site.

The reason, we have 5 languages (flags) is because we need to set 4 currency.

- DKK for Denmark
- SEK for Sweden
- NOK for Norway
- EUR for English + Germany

I'm trying to automatically redirect the users to the appropriate language based on the language set in their WordPress profile settings

- Danish language should redirect to Danish
- Norway language should redirect to Norway
- Swedish language should redirect to Swedish
- German language should redirect to German
- Everything else should be redirected to English

I found this in the WPML forum but couldn't get it to work.

```
//WPML Redirect user to his admin language
function switch_language($query){

    //GET user language
    $user_language = get_user_locale(get_current_user_id());
    //Format to language code (example : fr_FR -> fr)
    $user_lang_code = substr( $user_language, 0, 2 );

    //GET current language
    $current_lang = apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', NULL );

    if ( $current_lang != $user_lang_code && !$query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        //Current URL
        $url = "<em><u>hidden link</u></em>";
        //URL in user's language 
        $redirect_to = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $url , $user_lang_code );
        //Redirect
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'switch_language');
```

In my code, I replaced the hidden link with

```
http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

Could anyone please provide some advice?

Comment: Have you setup test users with different language preferences? One thing that stands out is `! $query->is_main_query()`, which basically says if it's not the main query. I would assume you want the main query. Another thing you can try is use the WPML constant for the current language `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` so do `$current_lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;`

Comment: Did you ever figure something out for this? I'd like to do something similar - always use the user's locale rather than have a language switcher on each page.